# Borwsers only open Google and Youtube

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, wireless-router

While working this morning on my Asus Lapotop, I suddenly couldn't access any other pages except for google and youtube. My Laptop is connected with wireless through a netgear router, which is connected to a Fastweb Modem. I can access any page with any of the other items connected to my net, wirelessly and thorugh ethernet. I can't even acces my gateway address from my asus laptop. I tried deleting cookies, changing browser, changing my DNS and powering off the modem, the router and the computer. Nothing happened. I'm starting to think that it can be a virus!

Comment: Is that only for chrome? Did you try `ping` other websites?

Answer (score 1):

“Only Google-owned sites load” is very commonly the most visible symptom of an MTU problem.

To see if that’s the case, adjust your laptop’s MTU down to 1300 and see if the problem goes away. If it does, try higher MTUs like 1400, 1450, 1480, etc to find the highest MTU that works.

Networks that don’t allow standard 1500-byte MTUs and that don’t automatically notify your devices of the problem are poorly designed or mismanaged. The most common MTU restriction is caused by PPPoE, which uses 8 bytes for PPP headers, leaving a 1492-byte MTU. Good PPPoE gateways should do “MSS Clamping” to keep clients from suffering from connectivity problems like this. Good routers should also support Path MTU Discovery by honoring the “don’t fragment” bit and sending the appropriate ICMP message when fragmentation is required. Good firewalls and NAT gateways should be sure to always forward those ICMP messages properly instead of dropping them.

Google knows about MTU problems so they configure all their servers to ask for a smaller MSS (TCP-level MTU), which causes all their packets to be slightly smaller (and thus slightly less efficient) than they could be, but allows them to still work for clients on MTU-broken networks even when others don’t. YouTube is owned by Google (er, maybe by Google’s parent “Alphabet” now) and follows Google’s practice.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer, but I don't get how did this happen in a fraction of a second...the second before everything worked perfectly then I try to reload a wikipedia pages and the problemm started.. I can't even acces my gateway!

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti If I’m wrong, adjusting your MTU won’t help and you can change it right back to 1500.

Comment: I tried but with 1300 it doesn't open youtube either! I switched it back to normal 1500 for my Wi-Fi